# Windows XP machine is not making 'event' sounds

Tags: windows-xp, audio

My neighbour has a machine running XP that no longer makes Windows 'event' sounds, such as the Startup/Shutdown sounds.  I've checked all the obvious things.  If I go in to edit the sound scheme, I can see the sounds are assigned to the event, I can click the little 'play' button and it plays the right sound.  It just won't make any noise on its own.

What really got me stumped was that if I click the volume icon in the system notification area and then start changing the volume, rather than a ding sound at various volumes from the speakers, all I get is a beep from the internal speaker.

It's an HP machine of some sort, with Realtek audio.

Comment: But he does have other sounds, like from media players and so?

Comment: wow.  i'd kill for a default Windows install that does this.  instead i have to go in and kill the sound scheme manually every time.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that the "Windows Audio" service is running:

- Click *"Start"*
- Click *"Run"*
- Type *"services.msc"*
- Double-Click *"Windows Audio"*
- Change *"Startup"* to *"Automatic"*
- Click *"Run"*
- Click *"OK"*

Comment: Thanks, that's one I hadn't thought of, I'll have to go round and take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Open the "Sounds and Audio Devices" control panel and click on the "Audio" tab.  Is the "Sound playback" "Default device" set to the Realtek device?

Comment: Sorry, I've been through all of those settings.  All was set correctly.